# How do you unsubscribe a subscriber at Business Unit Level?

Tags: marketing-cloud, email-studio

We have an enterprise 2.0 SFMC account and multiple Business units. All the business units have the same set of subscribers with same subscriber key.

If I unsubscribe a subscriber for "All Subscribers" List in a particular business unit, will the subscriber receive emails from other business units?

or the unsubscription is applicable to all business units under an Account?

Comment: I guess when you create Business Units there is an option to apply the unsubscribe status to all BU when changed in one BU

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, there is an option to unsubscribe the subscribes from All Business Unit level just by selecting an option under *Admin > Business Units* in Email Studio.

> Note: **Subscriber Key** has to be consistent across the account if needed to unsubscribe from all BU's.

[image]

Comment: no worries @PraveenKumarBandi. can you also upvote the answer? thank you